# Convert SVN Repository with multiple active branches to GIT

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, git-merge

I'm trying to convert my SVN Repository into a GIT repository.
The problem with this is, that in the SVN there are several active branches for
different software versions maintained in parallel.
So the SVN setup looks somthing like this:

```
SVN ROOT
|- trunk
|- branches
|  |- v1
|  |- v2
|  |- v3
|- tags
|  |- v1
|  |  |- 0
|  |  |- 1
|  |- v2
...
```

Now I want to create a GIT repository with a branch for each of the branches of
the SVN. Creating the repository and porting the tags is not a problem at all.
I'm doing a

```
git svn init -s --tags=tags/v1 --tags=tags/v2 <REPO_URL>
# modified .git/config to use tags/v1/* for the tags of the different versions
git svn fetch
```

and after this I get the branches as desired and I'm able to check out the different software versions by using

```
git checkout -b v1 origin/v1
```

The Problem is that the SVN Repository is verry old and the different branches all branch from the *trunk*. But my development requires me to fix a bug in
*v1*, merge it to *v2* as well and *dcommit* everything back to SVN.

So my question is what's the best way to get clean (mergable / rebaseable) GIT branches? And how should the workflow with this be?
Should I add a new branch for each version in GIT, let's say *svn_v1*, rebase the *v1* into this and then *dcommit* from there? Or what's the best way to get the commit back to SVN?

**EDIT**:

I've already tried to rebase the different branches according to the merge upstream (e.g. rebased *v2* onto *v1* and *trunk* onto *v2*) but this messed up
my histroy and when trying to *dcommit* it wanted to commit all the commits that I've rebased on top of the current history. This would make the SVN history messy as these commits already are in the Repo.

**EDIT2:**

To make the problem more clear. Imageine the following history:

```
        D--E--F v1  K--L--M v2
       /           /
A--B--C--G--H--I--J--N trunk
   ^
   |
   introduced a bug
```

As commit `B` introduced a bug, all branches `v1`, `v2`, and `trunk` are affected. The policy of my company is now (in SVN) to fix this issue in the lowest affected branch (`v1` in this case) and then merge the commit through the
branches up to `trunk`.
How does the workflow look like to do the same thing in GIT, such that in SVN the commit in `v1` is marked as being merged into `v2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally managed to solve this issue myself.
I've solved this in two steps: First of all, as our code bases for `v1` and `v2` are good (building and working, both with the known bugs fixed), I've recorded a merge of the `v1` branch into the `v2` branch and `v2` into `trunk` in `svn`.
Now I am able to merge the branches in `git`. Then I've found this passage in the `git-svn` docs:

> config key: svn.pushmergeinfo
>
> This option will cause git-svn to attempt to automatically populate the svn:mergeinfo property in the SVN repository when possible. Currently, this can only be done when dcommitting non-fast-forward merges where all parents but the first have already been pushed into SVN.

So I've enabled this config value

```
git config svn.pushmergeinfo true
```

and now, if a new bug is found, I'm fixing it in the lowest version that has this bug, `dcommit` it to `svn`, and afterwards merge it into the next version using the `--no-ff` option. If I `dcommit` now from there, the mergeinfos in `svn` get updated and everything is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to do your bugfix in `v1` and then cherry-pick that in `v2` before commiting both. This is not a merge nor a rebase operation in `git` terms. It would be if you would do the change in `v1`, then merge that into `master`, then merge-or-rebase that into `v2`.

I admit I'm not too sure where the problem is, after your description, though. It sounds more like a workflow problem then a git-svn problem to me? If your svn branches were good (i.e., not a total mess), then `git init` should have transfered them in a way that you can just work with them like usual. If they are already much degraded on the svn side, then it cannot "repair" that mess, really.

EDIT: To respond to your second edit: What you describe (distributing a hotfix/patch across all branches) is called "cherry-picking" in git, not merging. git does not (and does not need to) keep track of whether you did cherry-pick something or not; you just do it and are done with it. You most definitely do not want to do any merges or rebases in your scenario.

So, here's what you can do:

1. Your situation

   ```
           D--E--F v1  K--L--M v2
          /           /
   A--B--C--G--H--I--J--N trunk
      ^
      |
      introduced a bug
   ```
2. Fix your bug and commit on `v1`, if that is your policy.

   ```
   git checkout v1
   # fix bug
   git add ; git commit
   # note the commit hash you just created, let's call it a1b2c3d4
   ```
3. Distribute to the other branches

   ```
   git checkout v2
   git cherry-pick a1b2c3d4

   git checkout trunk
   git cherry-pick a1b2c3d4
   ```
4. New situation

   ```
           D--E--F--a1b2c3d4 v1    K--L--M--abcde123 v2
          /                      /
   A--B--C--G--H-------------I--J--N--bca123123 trunk
      ^
      |
      introduced a bug
   ```

That's it. `git cherry-pick` will automatically take the diff/patch for that single commit, apply it to your current HEAD, and create a new commit. There is (by design) nothing going on "backstage", it is a quite simple procedure. There may be conflicts as usual, which you may need to fix manually, but `git` will tell you what to do more or less clearly.

When you continue your regular work later, and merge/rebase those branches, `git` does not need to know about the cherry-picking. The stuff is inside your files, it will see (or not see) the textual differences, and with a bit of luck all will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, my question was for the workflow to use. If I understand the docs for cherry-picking correct, than this would two independent commits in SVN and not merge the commit on v1 into v2, does it? As the SVN is really old, I think the branches are already messed up. Question is, do I need to solve this in SVN first, or can I do this in GIT directly?

Comment: I would probably try to fix it after the conversion to `git` and then would not bother with mirroring it back into the `svn` world.

Comment: That would be my favorit, but the problem is, that the whole infrastructure (build system, CI, ect.) of my company is based on SVN, so an SVN mirror is required.

Comment: Ok, that's how I've understood cherry-picking. For `git` I'm fine with this. But in `svn` this would create 3 independent commits, wouldn't it? Because `git`, as you said, does not know that this is the changeset from another commit. Thus, I would get *3*, let's call them "real", commits, and not *1* "real" commit and *2* merge-commits